# Store reference to item in array

Tags: javascript, reference

I want the variable 'item' not only to store the value of the item in the array but also a reference to the array so when I change it it also changes in the original array.

```js
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
item = arr[2] // 'c'
item = 'f'
console.log(arr)
```

```
Output  : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Expected: ['a', 'b', 'f', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: JavaScript does not support references to scalar values. You can probably hack something together with implicit conversions, but not easily.

Comment: `item = arr[2];` then `item = 'f'`... Now, what do you think that the value of `item` is?

Comment: this doesnt work because `arr[2]` is `c` witch is an primitive value

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to both read and change values in an array but without calling the reference every single time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a horrible example of a horrible idea - and it only works in the root `global` scope. It takes advantage of the fact that top-level `var` variables are also *properties* on the `global` object (in web-browsers, the `window` object is also the `global` object):

```
Object.defineProperty( window, 'item', {
    get: function() { return window.arr[2]; },
    set: function( v ) { window.arr[2] = v; }
} );

var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

console.log( arr ); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
console.log( item ); // 'c'

item = 'f';

console.log( arr ); // ["a", "b", "f", "d", "e"]
console.log( item ); // 'f'

arr[2] = 'life is short and love is always over in the morning';

console.log( arr ); // ["a", "b", "life is short and love is always over in the morning", "d", "e"]
console.log( item ); // 'life is short and love is always over in the morning'
```

But you should never do this.

Comment: this will give programmer nightmares :P

Comment: That is a really nice approach, I hope I won't see it in the production...

Comment: so in nutshell user has to define multiple getter and setter for each array index.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Not necessarily. It depends on what they want to do, exactly. There are other shortcuts and tricks that can be employed to alias array elements.

Comment: This is wild. +1 for out of the box thinking, -1 for I hope no one ever does this 

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Dai horrible idea of modifying the properties of the window, I suggest even more scary solution of doing it dynamically with the usage of a proxy.

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

const handler = {
    get: (target, prop) => {
        Object.defineProperties(window, {
            item: {
                get: () => target[prop],
                set: (val) => target[prop] = val,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            }
        })
        return window.item;
    },
    set: (target, prop, val) => target[prop] = val
}

const arrayProxy = new Proxy(arr, handler);
item = arrayProxy[0];
console.log("item:", item);
item = "f";
console.log({item, arrayProxy, arr});
item = arrayProxy[1];
item = "g"
console.log({item, arrayProxy, arr});
```

This way it will work with indefinite length arrays as well. Take into account that item will refer only to a single element at a time so need to keep in mind asynchronous nature of javascript.

**However I strongly recommend against trying anything like this.**

Comment: Wow, this is awful :)

Comment: I like this a lot. And also hate it

Answer (score 1):

As others have said - this isn't how JS works with primitives.

But, I don't know you, and you may have a perfectly valid reason for doing so.

If you want to do this, I'd suggest being overly explicit so that other devs don't shoot themselves in the foot while interacting with your code.

Here I've created a Mutable class which holds a reference to a value. You can then use.

You can use the valueOf method to then allow your class to be used as a primitive. See the final line of the example, you can pull the value out of the array and then use it as if it's a number (without unwrapping via `array[0].value`).

Update - as @Dai suggested, added primitive check:

```js
class Mutable {
    constructor(value) {
        this.enforcePrimitive(value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    setValue(value) {
        this.enforcePrimitive(value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.value;
    }

    enforcePrimitive(value) {
        if (!this.isPrimitive(value) {
           throw new Error(`Non-primitive value passed to Mutable: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
       }
    }

    isPrimitive(test) {
        return (test !== Object(test));
    }
}


const array = [
    new Mutable(1),
    new Mutable(2),
    new Mutable(3),
];

console.log(array[0]); // Logs 1
const first = array[0];

first.setValue(2);
console.log(array[0]); // Logs 2

console.log(array[0] + 3); // Logs 5
```

Comment: Note that `valueOf` must return a _primitive_ value. I suggest you add `typeof` checks to the constructor and `setValue` to fast-fail when a non-primitive value is provided.

Comment: @Dai interesting, didn't know that. Do you know if there are cases where this throws errors if you don't provide a primitive?

Comment: honestly, no - because I never make mistaykes :)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't recommend doing it, but for science, you can wrap string to object. Then automatically you can retrieve an object and modify its value:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        'value': 'a'
    }
]
const item = arr[0] // {'value': 'a'}
item.value = 'c'
console.log(arr)
// {'value': 'c'}
```

How does it work? I recommend reading more about primitives & references:

- [JavaScript: Primitive vs Reference Values](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/)

But the short story is, that for primitives (which are string, number, bool) you can't have a reference. To solve that you need to wrap primitive to object (or an array, which is also an object).

But let me repeat, that is a bad coding style to use these hacks.